# Get the list of pages that customer visited yesterday

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console

Hi i am new to google analytics. Is there is any way to get the list of pages that our customer visited in our website with in a certain time period ?

i can see details in  **google analytics->behavior->all pages**and i can **filter results by date** also . But the thing is that i am not sue that this will record all visit of my customer  , because yesterday i visited some pages in my website , but google analytics not showing this page on the list

So please help  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that within several reports in Google Analytics, the easiest being within the **Audience** tab, called **User Explorer**:

[image]

These are based on the Client ID, which is a Cookie value uniquely set by Google Analytics for each visitor of your site (although it is not a proper Fingerprint ID, it does its job quite well).

Within the User Explorer, you'll see all Pageviews, Events and Goals each specific user made during their visit/s.

Comment: is there any way to distinguish my view from customers ? , is there is option like customer from japan ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not within the User Explorer. If you want to find your own Client ID, find your Google Analytics Cookie in your browser of choice. Just open up the console (Right Click -> Inspect, then go to Console tab) and enter `ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId')`. This should show you your own Client ID set by Google Analytics. Then search for that within the User Explorer report.

Comment: yes, i understand . I will check this .